# How does this Ruby block work from Eloquent Ruby?

Tags: ruby, enumeration

I understand that you you can pass variables to Ruby code blocks using `yield`
However,I'm lost as to what `yield` is doing here. I know there is some "Inception"
stuff going on.

```
def each_word
    words = %w(fuing wtrds iiha)
    words.each { | word | yield(word)  }
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your piece of code will run through all the words in `%w(fuing wtrds iiha)` (i.e. `"fuing", "wtrds", "iiha"`) and then `yield` each word to a block that is passed to the `each_word` method. For example, if you call the method like so:

```
each_word do | word |
    puts word
end
```

this will print out each word to the console; the output would be

```
fuing
wtrds
iiha
```

In my opinion, the code would be better written as:

```
words = %w(fuing wtrds iiha)
words.each do | word |
    puts word
end
```

as this will have the exact same effect.

Comment: Yes, your code and mine ( the Eloquent Ruby Book really) are equivalent. It's how yield is used that has me confused.

Comment: @lampshade I was attempting to explain that to you... what don't you understand, then?

Comment: I see what's going on with the use of yield now. If I rewrite it the long way

Answer (score -4):

Pass a block.

1.

```
each_word{|w| puts "**#{w}**"}
```

output

```
**fuing**
**wtrds**
**iiha**
```

2.

```
each_word{|w| puts w.capitalize}
```

output

```
Fuing
Wtrds
Iiha
```

etc.

Comment: -1 This does not answer the question, which is about the use of `yield` in a block.

Comment: The question is how that block (piece of code) cited in the question works. I showed by demonstrating it. The question is not about "the use of yield in a block".